# Convert String to Array in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

i Have column `to_user` in postgres db its type is of varchar it contains UUID. now i want to convert that column into an array of UUID. so i made a new column `to_user_copy` and copied data from `to_user` to `to_user_copy`.
i droped the `to_user` column and created a new column:

`ALTER TABLE "transactions" ADD "to_user" character varying array`

now i want to convert the UUID's present previouly into array of UUID's.

currently:

```
@Column("varchar" ,{name:'to_user', array: true })
    toUser: string[];
```

[current column types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMxbp.png)

[current Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zyvk.png)

now i want to convert the data present in `to_user_copy` to array and store it in `to_user`

```
          to_user_copy               |         to_user
---------------------------------------------------------------                
dc2544a6-5a5b-4268-9f31-9a9f8bae58aa |           NULL
```

```
          to_user_copy                |        to_user
---------------------------------------------------------------                
dc2544a6-5a5b-4268-9f31-9a9f8bae58aa  | {dc2544a6-5a5b-4268-9f31-9a9f8bae58aa}
```

Comment: UUIDs should be stored with the data type `uuid`, not in a `text` or `varchar` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a new column, to change a column from `text` to `text[]`

```
ALTER TABLE "transactions" 
   alter "to_user" type text[] 
   using array["to_user"];
```

However, UUIDs should be stored in columns defined with the data type `uuid`.

So this would be the preferred way:

```
ALTER TABLE "transactions" 
   alter "to_user" type uuid[] 
   using array["to_user"]::uuid[];
```